# Return rows filtering by jsonb object in array

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, jsonb

I have a table called `houses` and it has two columns `id` and a jsonb column called `details`. The `details` column has the following structure:

`[{ kind: "flat", price: 100 }, { kind: "circle", price: 10 }]`

I want to get all the `houses` which `details` column has at least one object where `kind` is `flat`.

This is what I have tried:

```
select *
FROM houses
WHERE "details"->>'kind' = 'flat'
```

Comment: You'd better to normalize your tables first: querying on 'blobs' is inefficient

Comment: @DDS sounds good your suggestion, however, do you know the answer to the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `jsonb_array_elements`

```
select h.*  from houses h cross join lateral 
    jsonb_array_elements(details) as j
where j->>'kind' = 'flat'
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=14d34a3f50f03edf42f4e24c1452d185)